# Boot loop after attempting to install SSD in an old computer

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I bought a Western Digital Blue 3D NAND 500 GB SSD to replace a mechanical disk in an old computer.   Until today the old computer was working.

After some initial trouble getting the computer to 'see' the Windows 10 installation USB I was able to successfully install Windows 10 onto the SSD.

The problems started when I rebooted after installing Windows 10.   It just powers down and reboots repeatedly after the usual BIOS loading (After IDE detection, where it would normally begin to load Windows, with the Windows logo displayed)

I have tried all kinds of things to get it to work,  even restoring the system back to the old state (old HD, SSD removed) but It just boot loops no matter what I do.

The motherboard is Gigabyte Killer E2100 G1 Guerrilla rev 1.    One thing I haven't tried is to flash the bios but that's risky so I wanted to explore all other avenues before that,  and this was working before today (In fact I had it working today before opening it up to install the SSD)

Another thing to mention is it is ignoring F12 (boot menu) .  I managed to get into the boot menu *once* to install Windows but ever since then the bios ignores my pressing F12

Comment: Unplug the PC power cord, open it up and remove the cmos battery for 2 minutes, reinsert the battery and power up, enter the bios immediately and set the date and time, save changes and exit. See if it will boot from the old drive now.

Comment: I did try removing the cmos battery but I can't recall if I had removed the new drive (so that I can boot from the old one).   I will try that now.

Comment: Have tried that now.  Still reboots after post.

Comment: @MrVimes Please clarify as to whether the PC is even loading the BIOS screen after POST or whether it's immediately shutting down during POST _(i.e. screen remains blank)_.  If the latter, it's a hardware issue - start by reseating the HDD cable, both on the HDD and the motherboard _(do not attempt to bypass this if it's failing POST, as doing so without fixing the source of the error will likely result in electrical damage to a component or components)_

Comment: Sorry,  by 'POST' I meant the bios stuff. I do see everything I would normally see before the windows logo.   It's when I would see the windows logo that it reboots.

Comment: Seem to have fixed it.  See my answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by plugging in the Bootable W10 installation USB, which for some reason allowed the F12 (Boot menu) to work.  I entered the boot menu and selected the SSD.  This worked and allowed Windows 10 to finalize its installation.

(I had a hunch, based on seeing via previous googling of the issue that the bios could be ignoring the boot order. Also had a hunch that the F12 menu needed the USB to be inserted in order to be accessible),

Answer (score -2):

Go into the BIOS settings and try turning on/off Legacy Boot and/or UEFI Boot

Comment: I don't recall seeing those settings but I will have another look.

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the OP's question... BIOS and UEFI firmware are not the same things.  @MrVimes That's because you don't have a motherboard with UEFI firmware - your motherboard has BIOS.